# Appending item in multiple dimensions list

Tags: python

I am not sure what this thing I am trying to do is called in Python, but how do I add items to a multi-dimension list? I know how to do it to a regular list, and I tried to figure out this array stuff but completely getting lost.

I want to make the list like this

```
portfolio_list =[
['TSLA',5000], 
['BA',2000], 
['MSFT',2000], 
['AAPL',1500],
]
```

I have this code in a while loop

```
new_item = input("Add stock ticker > ").upper()
add_to_list(new_item) #adds stock ticker to list 

new_value = input("What is value of {} > ".format(new_item))
add_item_value(new_value)
```

and the definitions I made for these are

```
def add_to_list(item): 
    portfolio_list.append([[item]],axis=0)
    print("{} has been added".format(item,))

def add_item_value(item):
    portfolio_list.append([[item]],axis=1)
    print("{} value has been added to {} ".format(item,new_item))
```

the error I am getting

```
Add stock ticker > tsla


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_effecient_frontier.py", line 139, in <module>
    add_to_list(new_item) #adds stock ticker to list
  File "test_effecient_frontier.py", line 70, in add_to_list
    portfolio_list.append([[item]],axis=0)
TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There is no such thing as a multidimensional list. `list` objects only have a length, i.e. a single dimension. Basically, you just want `portoflio_list.append([new_item, new_value])`

Comment: you might want to make a use of a dictionary for this use case, or just new class potentially. Otherwise, you need to find through loop where your ticker is, and append to that list

Comment: Hello fellow Jakub -- the `axis` keyword argument is common in numpy and pandas functions, not in the python standard library. Both of those libraries allow for multidimensional data representations (pandas uses numpy heavily under the hood).

Comment: Aah, I only called it multi-dimensional list because that is what it was called in Team Treehouse. Sorry I just started to learn to code in august  >.< still learning the correct terms

Comment: haha siema jakub :D

I am going to try and look up more on how the axis stuff works and try the submitted answer out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may

1. ask for both information
2. `append` the new sublist to the main `list`, dont forget to convert to `int`

```
portfolio_list = [
    ['TSLA', 5000],
    ['BA', 2000],
    ['MSFT', 2000],
    ['AAPL', 1500],
]

new_item = input("Add stock ticker > ").upper()
new_value = input("What is value of {} > ".format(new_item))
portfolio_list.append([new_item, int(new_value)])
```

With a while loop, you could have somethink like

```
while True:
    new_item = input("Add stock ticker > ").upper()
    if new_item == "STOP":
        break
    new_value = input("What is value of {} > ".format(new_item))
    portfolio_list.append([new_item, int(new_value)])
```